# What to do with opinion based questions which are accepted by the community?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, policy

There are some highly opinion-based questions in the system which are accepted by the community (has positive votes), but won't have any real answers. I see a contradiction among disciples.

An example for this: [Equation connected by lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/130310/equation-connected-by-lines)

This is an opinion-based but OK question. BUT it will remain unanswered forever which should not be a real use-case for a Q&A site. Am I right about that?

What is the policy about questions like this?

- they are just fine this way
- flag them as opinion-based? (doesn't seem like a good idea)
- should they be in a chatroom/forum instead of Q&A?
- should they have a discussion deadline?
- should it be migrated to meta/discussion after some time?
- other?

Comment: My opinion: opinion-based Q are ok (without answers sometimes) as long as it explores tweaks/hacks/inside details of TeX/LaTeX and improves best practices(efficiency/productivity).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

- We vote anything and everything.
- We are full of contradictions.
- If we somehow get what the point is we leave it alone unless it's really boring and unlikely to be done in finite amount of manhour **x** time **x** etc. That is another contradiction right there.
- We have monthly(biweekly?) *Answer the unanswered* sessions where we sweep the unanswered questions so most get filtered in those.
- There are really no rules other than mutual agreement and/or moderator's axe.
- Opinion-basedness is the essence of TeX-SX where everyone dictates what is more elegant or beautiful. Usually egreg wins the argument because we don't even understand the nuance unless David Carlisle intervenes. Then we really don't even understand what they are discussing or what the issue is all about. I recommend smiling and backing off with baby steps...

Comment: Hehe you are funny percusse, but you are right especially the last item :-)

Comment: I win because my tastes are the best. `;-)`

Comment: In other words, egreg and David are in the absolute zenith of TeX knowledge. `:)`